# What is wrong with Twitter API on iOs 8?

Tags: ios, objective-c, twitter

I want to create an action in Objetive-C that makes an instant "follow" in a Twitter Acount, but when I launch my app it crashes. Could anyone tell me what is wrong?

It returns `thread 1 exc_bad_access`.

```
- (IBAction)Twitter:(id)sender {

    ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
    ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

    [accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                       completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)  {
        if(granted) {

            NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

            if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {

                ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

                NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
                [tempDict setValue:@"user" forKey:@"UserName"];
                [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];

                NSURL *URLTwitter = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.format"];

                SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType:@"Twitter" requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:URLTwitter parameters:tempDict];

                [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

                [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                    NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %li", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                    NSLog(@"%@", output);

                }];
            }
        }
    }];
}
```

Comment: what's the crash stack?

Comment: It returns `thread 1 exc_bad_access`

Comment: You need to run it in the debugger. When it crashes type `bt` in the debugger console and paste the output here.

Comment: As a side note… any reason you're using `[tempDict setValue:@"user" forKey:@"UserName"];` instead of `tempDict[@"user"] = @"UserName"`?

Comment: @AshleyMills I think it is the same thing, isn't it?

Comment: The result is the same, it's just a more modern, succinct way of coding array access that's been around since iOS 6 (and also works under iOS 5)

Comment: @AshleyMills I didn't know it, maybe I start to use it. Thanks!

Comment: See http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-1/ and http://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/objective-c-literals-part-2/ for details

Answer (score 1):

Your twitter url is incorrect. It should be

`https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json`

Answer (score 0):

Here is what was wrong...
 1. Firstly, since the new Twitter API version 1.1 the correct URL is: `https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json`.
 2. The 'for key' value for the user name must to be "screen_name", and it will be like the following fragment:

```
NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
[tempDict setValue:@"UserNameOnTwitter" forKey:@"screen_name"];
[tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];
```

3. The value for 'requestForServiceType' must to be SLServiceTypeTwitter as the following:

   `SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:URLTwitter parameters:tempDict];`

So the whole block will be:

```
ACAccountStore *accountStore = [[ACAccountStore alloc] init];
ACAccountType *accountType = [accountStore accountTypeWithAccountTypeIdentifier:ACAccountTypeIdentifierTwitter];

[accountStore requestAccessToAccountsWithType:accountType options:nil
                                   completion:^(BOOL granted, NSError *error)  {
    if(granted) {

        NSArray *accountsArray = [accountStore accountsWithAccountType:accountType];

        if ([accountsArray count] > 0) {

            ACAccount *twitterAccount = [accountsArray objectAtIndex:0];

            NSMutableDictionary *tempDict = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
            [tempDict setValue:@"UserNameOnTwitterWithoutAt" forKey:@"screen_name"];
            [tempDict setValue:@"true" forKey:@"follow"];

            NSURL *URLTwitter = [NSURL URLWithString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/friendships/create.json"];

            SLRequest *postRequest = [SLRequest requestForServiceType: SLServiceTypeTwitter  requestMethod:SLRequestMethodPOST URL:URLTwitter parameters:tempDict];

            [postRequest setAccount:twitterAccount];

            [postRequest performRequestWithHandler:^(NSData *responseData, NSHTTPURLResponse *urlResponse, NSError *error) {
                NSString *output = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"HTTP response status: %li", [urlResponse statusCode]];
                NSLog(@"%@", output);
            }];
        }
    }
}];
```

Thanks anyway everyone.